Making Rascal AST visible in DSL
I am working on adding macros to my DSL. I want to know if it's possible to make the Rascal AST of my DSL accessible at the DSL layer so I can reference the AST directly. For example:
defmacro example(oldEntity : Entity):
  if oldEntity.simpleName == "Account":
    entity #{concat(oldEntity.simpleName, "_New")}{
      ...
    }
  else:
    entity #{oldEntity.simpleName}{
      ...
    }

Here, simpleName is a component of the Entity AST.

Note: The syntax above is just for illustration.


Yes, that's possible. The implementation will be trivial, but the design can be hard.
Every piece of information you have about the source program van be exposed to the programmer. If you are writing an interpreter, this is just the result of a Rascal function that produces that information. If you are writing a Compiler, you need to design access you that information at runtime. There would be a compile-time Rascal function that generates constants in code and methods that operate on these constants.
I'm guessing you are writing a lisp-like interpreter here. It's a matter of designing a "reflection API" for your language. Which functions and references will you provide, in which scopes, to the programmer? Your Interpreter may have to call eval on expressions which were previously static names only (so lookup becomes eval)

Thanks for the response, I don't fully get the questions "Which functions and references will you provide, in which scopes, to the programmer?". But if I get you correctly I need to implement (in the macro interpreter phase) some API that evaluates the AST expression during macro expansion.

Right! The question is what kind of protocol of communication you allow depends on things like .simpleName. Languages like Smalltalk have a elegant core of methods that allow for any kind of extensibility through querying runtime objects/classes. It's a matter of balancing power with safety how much you want to share with the programmer.

In the language I am implementing there is no such protocols like classes and objects that allows me to capture that.
I have considered implementing them as functions instead property access.
